# File I/O Error: filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to write a program in Java that accepts a CSV file as user input (either as a file name or file path). The program removes all whitespaces greater than or equal to 3, and replaces it with a comma. The program will then save the modified file to a new location with a user-specified name. I'm currently having difficulties reading files from the user. I get the following error message when I provide an input file:

```
An error occurred: "C:\...\buzz (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"
```

Here is my main method that runs the program:

```
package fileConverter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter file name or location:");
        String inputFile = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter output file name or location:");
        String outputFile = scanner.next();

        try {
            FileConverter.convertWhitespaceToComma(inputFile, outputFile);
            System.out.println("Conversion complete. Output written to " + outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally { 
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This main method calls "FileConverter.java" which is provided below:

```
package fileConverter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FileConverter {

    public static void convertWhitespaceToComma(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws IOException {

        // Create a regex pattern for matching whitespace sequences of length 3 or more
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s{3,}");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // Replace all matched whitespace sequences with commas
            String modifiedLine = line.replaceAll(pattern.pattern(), ",");
            bw.write(modifiedLine);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

I have a try-catch block in main which prints an error message (`e.getMessage()`), and that is where this error message is coming from:

```
An error occurred: "C:\...\buzz (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"
```

When I compile and run the program this is what comes out of the terminal:

```
Enter file name or location:
"C:\...\buzz lightyear\...\File Converter\src\fileConverter\<filename.txt>"
Enter output file name or location:
An error occurred: "C:\Users\buzz (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
C:\...\buzz lightyear\...\File Converter>
```

I know there are probably other issues with my code, but let me get this figured out and I will work on tackling the rest!

Any help and/or suggestions are appreciated. I am just trying to identify why the file can't be recognized. Thank you!

As a workaround, I tried providing the file name instead of the full path, but I get this error message instead:

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: It looks like the space in the name of the directory is causing a process to be confused.  As a test, copy the directory to `buzz_lightyear` , use that, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: `Scanner.next()` is doing this. Use `Scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: okay, I changed the method from scanner.next() to scanner.nextLine(). I am still getting the error message: "C:\Users\buzz lightyear\Desktop\File Converter\src\fileConverter\<file name>" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)", but I will try changing the file directory to buzz_lightyear. Thanks for the help so far, everyone.

Comment: Using a debugger, set a breakpoint, and check what `inputFile` and `outputFile` actually contain.

Comment: If the problem is caused by the space in `buzz lightyear`, it would also be caused by the space in `File Converter`.  So, change `buzz lightyear` to `buzz_lightyear` **and** `File Converter` to `File_Converter` and anywhere else a space occurs in the pathname.

Comment: Please post your current code. Edit it into your question, without removing the original code.

Comment: Also print out names of the paths before you use them, the text you've shown can't match what happens if you've switched to `nextLine()`. Don't type in quotes or extra leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Seeing that you expect to enter 2 items from the console, may I suggest using an alternative to `scanner = new Scanner (System.in);`?  For debugging, just after `public static void main (String [] args) {`, add this line: `System.out.println("Starting program with " + args.length + " args: " + Arrays.toString(args) + "\n");`. Instead of using `scanner`, create 2 aliases: `String inputFile = args[0]; String outputFile = args[1];`. When you run the program, include the names or pathnames of the files on the command line. You might want throw an exception if `args.length != 2`.

Comment: Example run: `java -jar misc3.jar "fee fie foe fum" red green blue "\"Pat\" \"Chris\" \"Sandy\""`  Output: `Starting program with 5 args: [fee fie foe fum, red, green, blue, "Pat" "Chris" "Sandy"]`. This does not attempt to use file names. It shows a quoted String with 3 spaces, 3 Strings, each of which have no whitespace, and  a String with embedded quotes. Note the commas in the output.